# Merging dataframes with arrays in columns

Tags: python, pandas

In `pandas`, how to merge two datasets so that arrays contained in columns concatenates ?

For instance, let `d1` and `d2` two datasets to be merged. In my case I have around 100 relatively small dataframes to merge:

```
>> d1  
        id       seq
0   AAA         (1, 2, 3, 4)
1   BBB         (1, 2, 3, 4) <---

>> d2
        id       seq
0   CCC         (1, 2, 3, 4)
1   DDD         (1, 2, 3, 4)
2   BBB         (5, 6, 7) <---
```

Now we want:

```
>> df
      id          seq
    AAA         (1, 2, 3, 4)
    BBB         (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) <---
    DDD         (1, 2, 3, 4)
    CCC         (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How to do that efficiently ?

I tried merged but it seems I'm obliged to pass by the method `apply` which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use tuples/lists/dicts in DataFrame, because lost vecorizing in pandas functions.

Solution if tuples in `seq` column:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('ip')['seq']
       .apply(lambda x: tuple([z for y in x for z in y]))
       .reset_index()
print (df)
            ip                    seq
0   110.11.1.5  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
1  115.65.20.1           (1, 2, 3, 4)
2   118.11.1.5           (1, 2, 3, 4)
3   55.65.85.1           (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Performance with flattening is a bit better:

```
dfs = [df1, df2] * 50

In [57]: %timeit pd.concat(dfs).groupby('ip',as_index=False).seq.sum()
15.7 ms ± 452 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [58]: %timeit pd.concat(dfs).groupby('ip')['seq'].apply(lambda x: tuple([z for y in x for z in y])).reset_index()
7.86 ms ± 72.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('id',as_index=False).seq.sum()
Out[860]: 
  id                 seq
0  A        (1, 2, 3, 4)
1  B  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
2  C        (1, 2, 3, 4)
3  D        (1, 2, 3, 4)
```